# find patern text in Java and replace to another pattern

Tags: java

I have a paragraph of text numbers with specific format 
e.g "123-21-1234 this is another text - some text 222-34-2244 another text"

I need to select the specific numbers ( 123-21-1234 and 222-34-2244) and convert them to "123/21/1234 this is another text - some text 222/34/2244 another text"

Comment: What have you tried?  I would recommend looking into [`String.replaceAll(String, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Yes, string replace will replace all occurrences, I only need to format the specific numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below using Matcher.appendReplacement

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "123-21-1234 this is another text - some text 222-34-2244 another text";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{3})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{4})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {            
        String num = m.group();
        m.appendReplacement(sb, num.replace('-', '/'));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: This seems a lot clunkier than just using `String.replaceAll`

Answer (score 0):

Using `.replaceAll("-", "/")` has some annoying side effects

Instead you can look for the String literal to replace, or craft your own regex

```
string.replaceAll("123-21-1234", "123/21/1234").replaceAll("222-34-2244", "222/34/2244");
```

If you wish to match any XXX-XX-XXXX patterns

```
string.replaceAll("(\\d{3})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{4})", "$1/$2/$3");
```

This works by looking for the digit sequence, putting the digits into groups ($0 is the whole match, $1 is the first ()s, $2 is second ()s...)